# 3d point cloud visualization & remove outliers

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, point-clouds

I have xyz file which contains 3d point cloud. I want to visuazlie 3d images and remove blank spaces by using jupyter notebook. Although I tried so many different ways to visualize and remove noise, I have no idea how to visualize it. I used numpy and matplotlib as my library. Since I cannot find enough information on online regarding point cloud in python, I sincerely need help with solving this issue.

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52226098/13563675), you can use open3d to visualize point cloud.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of "remove blank spaces" is quite confusing. A point cloud means points scatter in the space, and a "point" is a mathematical concept that doesn't occupy any space.

Anyway, for visualization and some basic processing like, outlier removal, you may want to have a look at Open3D. Here is the links to its documentation on

Visualization: http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/geometry/pointcloud.html

Downsample and outlier removal: http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/geometry/pointcloud_outlier_removal.html